# Retain values till there is a change in value in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

There is a transaction history table in teradata where balance gets changed only when there is a transaction 
Data as below:

```
Cust_id Balance Txn_dt
123     1000    27MAY2018
123     350     31MAY2018
```

For eg,For a customer(123) on May 27 we have a balance of 1000 and on May 31 there is a transaction made by the customer so balance becomes 350. There is no record maintained for May 28 to May 30 with same balance as on May 27 . I want these days data also to be there (With same balance retained and the date is incremented ) Its like same record has to be retained for rest of the days till there is a change in a balance done by the transaction . How to do this in teradata? 
Expected output:

```
Cust_id Balance Txn_dt
123     1000    27MAY2018
123     1000    28MAY2018
123     1000    29MAY2018
123     1000    30MAY2018
123     350     31MAY2018
```

Thanks
Sandy

Hi Dnoeth. It seems to work, but can you let me know how to expand till a certain day for eg : till 30JUN2018 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get this result, the simplest in Teradata utilizes Time Series Expansion for Periods:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT Cust_id, Balance, Txn_dt,
      -- return the next row's date
      Coalesce(Min(Txn_dt)
               Over (PARTITION BY Cust_id 
                     ORDER BY Txn_dt
                     ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following)
              ,Txn_dt+1) AS next_Txn_dt
   FROM tab
 ) 
SELECT Cust_id, Balance
  ,Last(pd) -- last day of the period
FROM cte
-- make a period of the current and next row's date
-- and return one row per day
EXPAND ON PERIOD(Txn_dt, next_Txn_dt) AS pd
```

If you run TD16.10+ you can replace the `MIN OVER` with a simplified `LEAD`:

```
Lead(Txn_dt)
Over (PARTITION BY Cust_id 
      ORDER BY Txn_dt)
```