# Retain value till a certain date in teradata

Tags: teradata

Below is the link of my previous quetsion. It worked as suggested by one of the community members @Doneth.
But when I use '2018-05-31' in coalesce , i'm getting an error saying 'datatype mismatch in if/then else statement'.

Query used:

```
with cte 
{
  SELECT customer_id, bal, st_ts,
      -- return the next row's date
      Coalesce(Min(st_ts)
               Over (PARTITION BY customer_id 
                     ORDER BY st_ts
                     ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following)
              ,'2018-05-31') AS next_Txn_dt
   FROM BAL_DET;
}
SELECT customer_id, bal
  ,Last(pd) -- last day of the period
FROM cTE
-- make a period of the current and next row's date
-- and return one row per day
EXPAND ON PERIOD(ST_TS, next_Txn_dt) AS pd;
```

Link to my question:
[Retain values till there is a change in value in Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850153/retain-values-till-there-is-a-change-in-value-in-teradata)

Comment: The columns used in `coalesce` have different data types, `'2018-05-31'` is a string, but you need a date `'DATE '2018-05-31'`

Comment: Hi @Doneth, sorry yes I checked some previous post and did the same, but it was retained only till 30MAY2018 and not till 31MAY2018. Kindly advise. Can I try DATE '2018-05-31' + 1 ? Thanks.

Comment: A `period` is always *including* the start but *excluding* the end, simply add one day.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dnoeth

Comment: Hi. I am getting an error like 'Invalid period value constructor, The biginning bound must be less than the ending bound . Kindly advise.

Coalesse used is :      Coalesce(Min(st_ts)
               Over (PARTITION BY customer_id 
                     ORDER BY st_ts
                     ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following)
              ,Date '2018-05-31' + 1) AS next_Txn_dt

Comment: As the error message implies: There's either some bad data or the `st_ts` of the latest row is > 2018-05-31. Deoending on what you want in your result you  might add a `WHERE st_ts <= DATE '2018-05-31'` to remove those rows.