# Retain values only for certain section of data in teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Below is the link of my previous quetsion.
[Retain values till there is a change in value in Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850153/retain-values-till-there-is-a-change-in-value-in-teradata)

It worked as suggested by one of the community members @Dnoeth. Can this retention be done only for certain section of data?

I.e, Retain data only for data where Dep is A or B . When Dep is C just use same value as input and no need to retain till certain value.

```
Data:
Cust_id Balance st_ts          Dep
123     1000    27MAY2018 A
123     350     31MAY2018  A
256     2000   29MAY2018  B
345     1000   28APR2018   C
345     1200   26MAY2018   C
```

Output reqd:

```
Cust_id Balance st_ts         Dep
123     1000    27MAY2018 A
123     1000    28MAY2018 A
123     1000    29MAY2018 A
123     1000    30MAY2018 A
123     350     31MAY2018  A
256     2000   29MAY2018  B
256     2000   30MAY2018  B
256     2000    31MAY2018 B
345     1000   28APR2018   C
345     1200   26MAY2018   C
```

Query used:

```
Wth cte
{
  SELECT customer_id, bal, st_ts,
      -- return the next row's date
      Coalesce(Min(st_ts)
               Over (PARTITION BY customer_id 
                     ORDER BY st_ts
                     ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following)
              ,Date '2018-06-01') AS next_Txn_dt
   FROM BAL_DET;
}
SELECT customer_id, bal
  ,Last(pd) -- last day of the period
FROM cTE
-- make a period of the current and next row's date
-- and return one row per day
EXPAND ON PERIOD(ST_TS, next_Txn_dt) AS pd;
```

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: Can you just add a where clause to your CTE for the ones you want to expand, and then union in the ones you don't want to expand?

Comment: Hi @Andrew. Thanks for your reply. There is few other columns too which I just want to retain across the data. If I include it, I am getting an error saying 'inbound must be lesser than outer bound' . If I dont include it seems to be fine . How to rectify this?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a CASE to check for `Dep = 'C'`:

```
WITH cte AS 
(  SELECT customer_id, bal, st_ts, dep,
      -- return the next row's date
      CASE
        WHEN dep = 'C' 
           THEN st_ts +1 -- simply increase date
        ELSE
           Coalesce(Min(st_ts)
                    Over (PARTITION BY customer_id 
                          ORDER BY st_ts
                          ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following)
                   ,DATE '2018-06-01')
      END AS next_Txn_dt
   FROM BAL_DET
)
SELECT customer_id, bal
  ,Last(pd) -- last day of the period
  ,dep
FROM cTE
-- make a period of the current and next row's date
-- and return one row per day
EXPAND ON PERIOD(ST_TS, next_Txn_dt) AS pd
```

Comment: Hi @dnoeth. Thanks for your reply. There is few other columns too which I just want to retain across the data. If I include it, I am getting an error saying 'inbound must be lesser than outer bound' . If I dont include it seems to be fine . How to rectify this?Thanks.

Comment: @Sandy: Without knowing your actual query and how your data & expected result looks like, it's impossible to help.